# Create Clustered/Non Clustered Index in view

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am having a view which returns value to a table. The process takes a long time... So I felt it works better if go for indexing on view. Can anyone plz guide me to add index to view.

```
ALTER View [dbo].[GetApplicationBudgetAndUtilized]
as

Select *, (convert(money,isnull(TotalBudget,0)) - convert(money,isnull(Utilized,0))) as [Left] from (
SELECT Distinct PM.PKID AS ProgramID, F.PKID as FundID, I.PKID as ProjectID,
MYB.PKID AS MultiYearBudgetID,
(Select Isnull(Sum(IsNull(PBC1.BudgetAmount,0)),0) from ProgramBudgetConfiguration PBC1
Where pbc1.MultiYearBgtIdFkId = pbc.MultiYearBgtIdFkId and PBC1.IsActive = 1 and LOVBudgetTypeIDFKID = 'BT_INC' group
by pbc1.MultiYearBgtIdFkId) AS TotalProgramBudget,
App.TotalBudget,
I.PKID,

(Case when exists (Select 'x' from InstallationTransactionHeader Where ParentPrjNumber = I.PKID and IsDelete = 0)
then
(case
when not exists (select cast(isnull(I1.CustInstallIncAmt,0.00) + isnull(I1.SPInstIncentiveAmt,0.00) + isnull(I1.ThirdPartyIncentive,0.00) as Money)
from InstallationTransactionHeader I1 where I1.ParentPrjNumber is not null and I1.StatusFKID in ('ITS_SUB','ITS_APP','ITS_VRF') and
I1.ParentPrjNumber = I.PKID and I1.FundRequestIDFKID is not null) then (select '0')
else
(select isnull(sum(cast(isnull(I1.CustInstallIncAmt,0.00) + isnull(I1.SPInstIncentiveAmt,0.00) + isnull(I1.ThirdPartyIncentive,0.00) as Money)),0)
from InstallationTransactionheader I1 where I1.StatusFKID in ('ITS_SUB','ITS_APP','ITS_VRF') and I1.ParentPrjNumber is not null and
I1.ParentPrjNumber = I.PKID and I1.isdelete = 0 and I1.FundRequestIDFKID is not null group by I1.parentPrjNumber)
End)
else
--isnull(cast(isnull(I.CustInstallIncAmt,0.00) + isnull(I.SPInstIncentiveAmt,0.00) + isnull(I.ThirdPartyIncentive,0.00) as Money),0)
(case
when not exists (select isnull(cast(isnull(I.CustInstallIncAmt,0.00) + isnull(I.SPInstIncentiveAmt,0.00) + isnull(I.ThirdPartyIncentive,0.00) as Money),0) from
InstallationTransactionHeader I where StatusFKID in ('ITS_SUB','ITS_APP','ITS_VRF') and IsDelete = 0 and
PKID = I.PKID and I.FundRequestIDFKID is not null) then 0--(select '0')
else
(select isnull(sum(cast(isnull(I1.CustInstallIncAmt,0.00) + isnull(I1.SPInstIncentiveAmt,0.00) + isnull(I1.ThirdPartyIncentive,0.00) as Money)),0)
from InstallationTransactionheader I1 where I1.StatusFKID in ('ITS_SUB','ITS_APP','ITS_VRF') and IsDelete = 0 and I1.FundRequestIDFKID is not null and
PKID = I.PKID)
End)
End) as Utilized

--Cast(App.TotalBudget - (isnull(I.CustInstallIncAmt,0.00) + isnull(I.SPInstIncentiveAmt,0.00) + isnull(I.ThirdPartyIncentive,0.00)) as Money) as [Left]
FROM
( SELECT PKID as FundID, ProgramID AS ProgramID, (ISNULL(IncentiveAmount,0.00) + ISNULL(CustInstallIncAmt, 0.00) + ISNULL(SPInstIncentiveAmt, 0.00) ) AS TotalBudget
FROM dbo.FundRequestHeader AS F WHERE (IsDelete = 0) AND (IsActive = 1) AND (StatusFKID in ('IAS_APP','IAS_CAN'))) AS App
INNER JOIN dbo.ProgramMaster AS PM
INNER JOIN dbo.MultiYearBudget AS MYB ON PM.PKID = MYB.ProgramIDFKID
INNER JOIN dbo.ProgramBudgetConfiguration AS PBC ON MYB.PKID = PBC.MultiYearBgtIdFkId ON App.ProgramID = PM.PKID
INNER JOIN dbo.FundRequestHeader AS F ON F.PKID = App.FundID
INNER JOIN dbo.InstallationTransactionHeader AS I ON I.FundRequestIDFKID = F.PKID
WHERE (PM.IsActive = 1) AND (MYB.IsActive = 1) AND (PBC.IsActive = 1) AND
(PBC.LOVBudgetTypeIDFKID = 'BT_INC') And (F.StatusFKID in ('IAS_APP','IAS_CAN'))
--and (1=case when(select ProgramTypeIDFKID from InstallationTransactionHEader where ProgramTypeIDFKID='IT_PRE' and ParentPrjNumber is null and PaymentSchedule=1)='IT_PRE' then 0 else 1 end)
--and I.ProgramTypeIDFKID <> 'IT_PRE' or I.PaymentSchedule = 0 or (I.ProgramTypeIDFKID = 'IT_PRE' and I.PaymentSchedule = 1 and I.ParentPrjNumber is not null)
and MYB.PKID = F.BudgetPeriodID and ((MYB.IsActive = 1))-- or ((MYB.status = 0) and F.StatusFKID ='IAS_APP'))
and (MYB.Status = 1 or (MYB.Status =(case when exists(select M.status from MultiYearBudget M, FundRequestHeader F
where F.ProgramID=M.ProgramIDFKID and F.ProgramTypeIDFKID <>'IT_FCFS' and M.Pkid=F.BudgetPeriodID
and F.StatusFKID='IAS_APP' and F.ProgramID=PM.PKID and M.Status=0 )then 0 else 1 end))

)
)temp

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexed views have certain [limitations](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx)

In your case, I can immediately see some blockers

- `SELECT *`
- Derived tables

So read this article, and see how far you get...

However, you should be able to look the execution plan identify bottlenecks where you can add indexes to the bases tables

Comment: I am unable to view the article... It's showing up some web page problem... Can u plz guide me further...

Comment: Thank U... It's good now... I read it and let u know if I face any road blocks.